# Adding a foreign key to my table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue

```
create table REALESTATE (
reale_id        integer,
agents_id       integer not null,
listing_id      integer not null,
primary key (reale_id)
);
```

****TABLE CREATED****

```
create table AGENTS (
 agents_id  integer,
agents_name  char(10) not null,
agents_lname char(20) not null,
listing_id  integer,
customer_id integer,
reale_id    integer, 
primary key (agents_id),
foreign key (customer_id) references AGENT (customer_id),
foreign key (reale_id) references REALESTATE (reale_id)
);
```

ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
create table CUSTOMER (
customer_id     integer,
customer_name   char(6) not null,
customer_lname  char(15) not null,
agents_id       integer,
primary key (customer_id),
foreign key (agents_id) references AGENTS (agents_id)
);
```

ERROR at line 7: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 0):

In the create table for agents, you have this line.

```
foreign key (customer_id) references AGENT (customer_id),
```

However, table agent does not exist.  Only table realestate exists at this point.  This means that table agents did not get created which causes the problem with table customer.

Answer (score 0):

The table name is AGENTS not AGENT.

Change `foreign key (customer_id) references AGENT (customer_id),` to `foreign key (customer_id) references AGENTS
 (customer_id),`

Answer (score 0):

Table `AGENTS` wasn't created because it references a table named `AGENT` (see missing `S`) which doesn't exist. As creation of `AGENTS` failed you cannot create `CUSTOMERS` because it references `AGENTS` as well which was not created (due to the error before).

In table `AGENTS`: use `references AGENTS (customer_id)`.